# Undetectable capacitor

Tags: voltage, capacitor, ceramic

Hi I have this component which I suppose is a ceramic capacitor, it is soldered into a Bose 901 Equalizer series IV and between 2 output leads of the main transformer in parallel to a bulb signalling operation is on. My question is what I have to order/look for if i want to replace it? Thanks[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to replace it? It looks fine to me ...

Answer (score 5):

As with a lot of popular audio products, someone has usually taken the time to redraw the complete schematic. Here's the section I think you require: -

[image]

C1 is a 4.7 nF cap and is indeed connected across the input supply and lamp. Given that the circuit shows it directly across the 120 Vac supply I would suggest an X type capacitor because it is designed to work directly to a line with minimal risk of causing a fire: -

[image]

The original one may be an X type but you should at least comply with standards suitable for today. If in any doubt, it's probably worth buying the technical manual containing the proper schematic - from what I can tell it's about $20.

Answer (score 2):

That capacitor looks detectable. I can see it clearly.

It's most likely the capacitor rating in µF so 4.7 nF.

Answer (score 2):

4.7 nF ceramic, radial disc type , 2~3kV (judging by lead spacing). general purpose ( any type) for RF/ESD filter.  But depending on circuit probably isn't high voltage just conveniently rugged.
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-bc-components/S472M47Z5UP65K0R/1289PH-ND/2356825